# Why does selecting elements by the accessible name and checked state not work here?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test where I select all the checked checkboxes using React Testing Library. I am able to use `wrapper.getAllByRole('checkbox');` to get all of the checkboxes, but once I try to get the ones that are checked with `wrapper.getAllByRole('checkbox', { checked: true });` then I get the error messaage:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "checkbox"
```

I saw that in the [official docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/), this is listed as a possibility so I'm not sure why it doesn't work here.

Even stranger, is that I can see that the checkbox elements are shown in the console:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "checkbox"

Here are the accessible roles:

checkbox:

      Name "":
      <button
        aria-checked="false"
        class="checkbox-module_checkbox__obRBR"
        data-state="unchecked"
        role="checkbox"
        type="button"
        value="folderType"
      />

      Name "":
      <button
        aria-checked="false"
        class="checkbox-module_checkbox__obRBR"
        data-state="unchecked"
        role="checkbox"
        type="button"
        value="fileType"
      />

      ...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `queryAllByRole` works; perhaps whatever `getAllByRole` was returning was the issue